# In my Rails controller test, why am I getting NoMethodError: undefined method 'formats' for string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add tests for an existing application that's a bit unconventional. I can get it to render a page fine on the dev server. But when I add a controller test, I get the following error whenever I render a view:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `formats' for "foo":String
test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:DashboardControllerTest>'
```

Here's the code:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'foo', to: 'dashboard#foo'

# app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    #render plain: 'ok'
  end
end

# app/views/dashboard/foo.html.erb
ok!

# app/views/layouts/application.rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

# test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class DashboardControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "get foo" do
    get :foo
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I visit `/foo` in my browser and I get `ok!`.

I run my tests and I get the error above.

If I uncomment the `render plain` line in `DashboardController#foo`, the test passes.

It would appear something's breaking when the test tries to render the view, but I can't figure out what and the error message isn't offering me much help. What does this error mean?

---

#### Update

Just noticed that the application is using [render_anywhere gem](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere). I wonder if this has something to do with it.

Comment: With `render plain` you are specifying that it is ok to visit the endpoint without an extension. Otherwise an extension such as `foo.html` or `foo.json` is expected to specify the format to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the `render_anywhere` gem indeed solved the issue. It was being included in a rake task.

The rake task is not being tested, so I simply side-stepped the issue for now like so:

```
unless Rails.env.test?
  require 'render_anywhere'
  include RenderAnywhere
end
```